# User Input isn't noticed within a function

Tags: python, function

i have a question regarding a function. During the first part i asked the user to input an number, so that i can use it input for a function, but it doesn't notice this input.

```
 def Hi():
    n = raw_input('1-4')
    if n == 1:
        print 'Hello'
```

Comment: `n` is a string and will never be equal to an integer. Compare it to `"1"` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to convert input string to `int`

```
def Hi():
    n = int(raw_input('1-4'))
    if n == 1:
        print 'Hello'
```